# extracting/copy ranges of columns from large data file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I was trying to prepare data files from one large file by extracting columns and pasting into a new file.

The number of columns of the given data is very large. I want to prepare a number of data files by splitting the data.
I was trying the script below, but it is not working. I expect the error is due to specifying ranges of columns to copy.

```
#!/bin/bash

paste <(awk '{print $1,$2,$3,...$19,$20}' Precipitation.csv ) > aaaaa1
paste <(awk '{print $21,$22,$23,...$39,$40}' Precipitation.csv ) > aaaaa2 
paste <(awk '{print $41,$42,$43,...$99,$100}' Precipitation.csv ) > aaaaa3
```

Would you please help me in correcting the code?

Comment: You don't show what the error message is or say exactly how it's not working. Are you including the ellipses or did you just do that in order to shorten the lines for posting the question? I don't think `paste` with one argument usually is very useful.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a case where [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) will do better than `awk`:

```
cut -d , -f1-20 Precipitation.csv > aaa1
cut -d , -f21-40 Precipitation.csv > aaa2
cut -d , -f41-100 Precipitation.csv > aaa3
```

`-d ,` specifies the delimiter (a comma, since the input is called CSV, but you can change that). `-f N-M` picks out fields `N` through `M` inclusive to be in the output. If there are embedded commas within any field it will break - in that case you probably want a real CSV parser, although it is possible to hack something together if that really isn't possible.

The output will use the same delimiter as the input. GNU `cut` supports a [`--output-delimiter=STRING`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) option to set a different delimiter, but I don't think any others do. FreeBSD's `cut` includes a [`-w`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cut&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%209.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) split-by-whitespace option that is closer to what `awk` does by default. If you want one of those behaviours elsewhere, transforming the delimiter before/after is probably your best bet.

Comment: @Micheal Homer, thank you very much. It worked!

Answer (score 2):

A follow-up on [Michael Homer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148452/22565):

To avoid reading the file several times with shells supporting process substitution (`ksh`, `zsh`, `bash`):

```
 tee < Precipitation.csv >(cut -d, -f1-20 > aaa1) >(cut -d, -f21-40 > aaa2) | 
   cut -d, -f41- > aaa3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```
perl -F',' -anle 'print join ",", @F[0..19]' Precipitation.csv > aaa1
perl -F',' -anle 'print join ",", @F[20..39]' Precipitation.csv > aaa2
perl -F',' -anle 'print join ",", @F[40..99]' Precipitation.csv > aaa3
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, this should be all you need - and it's all processed in a single stream, so you should handle the big file much more efficiently that way.

I did a small test on this like:

```
{   sed -e '/\n\n/{s///w aaa3
    d' -e '};s/,/\n/20;P;G;D' |
    sed -ne 'w aaa1' -e 'n;p'
} <<DATA > aaa2
$(
    seq -s, 100 | tee - - - -
)
DATA
```

Then I printed the results like:

```
for f in 1 2 3
do  printf '\n%s\n' aaa$f
    cat aaa$f
done
```

And success!

```
aaa1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

aaa2
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40

aaa3
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100
```

Answer (score 0):

This provides better performance as we are reading the input file only once

```
awk '{out1=$1; for(i=2; i<=20; i++) {out1 = (out1 FS $i)}
  out2=$21; for(i=22; i<=40; i++) {out2=(out2 FS $i)}
  out3=$41; for(i=42; i<=100; i++) {out3=(out3 FS $i)}
  print out1 > "aaaaa1"; print out2 > "aaaaa2"; print out3 > "aaaaa3"}' Precipitation.csv
```

or you can type all the field numbers in the below command. Replace '...' with all the required field numbers

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,...$19,$20 > "aaaaa1";
  print $21,$22,$23,...$39,$40 > "aaaaa2";
  print $41,$42,$43,...$99,$100 > "aaaaa3"}' Precipitation.csv
```